# NaN in CNN Loss after using the self.model.predict in a TF callback

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tpu

I am training a modified YOLOv3 which always converges at batch size 64. Now when I use `self.model.predict()` inside a subclassed `tf.keras.callbacks` to predict the mAP **on epoch end**
I get a NaN loss at the start of the second epoch.

```
with strategy.scope():
  model = model_def()
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(tfDataset, callbacks=[custom_cb]

class custom_cb(tf.keras.callbacks) :
  def compute(self,...):
  ...

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    pred = self.model.predict(...)
    metric = self.compute(pred, ...)
    tf.print(metric)
```

I am using the TPU VM accelerator in Kaggle with Tensorflow 2.12.

Comment: Does this happen if you reduce your learning rate?
You can use tf.print to print important tensors. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print
Also consider logging many metrics to get an inside what might cause NaN.

Comment: @Gagik I have reduced the learning rate but the issue still persist. This only happens if I call self.model.predict in a tf callback.

Comment: Could you add `tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()` at the beginning and see if it helps to get more info why NaN is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()` to localize where infinity or NaN happens:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()

Training code here
```

This will slow down your training, use it only for debugging NaN issue.

For details please check [tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/enable_check_numerics)